# Safety/Encryption for python script (bot)

Tags: python, encryption

I built a python script (bot) for a game and I do plan on building a GUI for it to make it more user friendly. However I wanted to add some sort of security along with it, something that would **only** give access to *whoever* I want, so *maybe* adding some kind of encryption key to it, I was thinking something along the lines of an encrypted key to unlock the files and with limited use(a few days for example). I am new when it comes to this specific 'security' topic, so I need help better understanding what my options are and what I can do or search for. Thank you for reading.

Comment: How will this bot be used by other people?  Is it a program that they download and run locally on their computer, or is it accessed over the web?

Comment: Hello John, thank you for your reply. It will be a bot that they download and will run locally on their computer, the bot uses python and selenium on its source code.

Answer (score 0):

after days of searching and trying I figured the easiest way was to use a web API to check requests, you can use for example cryptolens web api or any other api and your encrypted file will work just fine.